# Recover Visual Studio 2010 macros from a previous install?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-macros

I'll keep it short and simple. I had a OCZ Vertex 100Gb SSD that I had my operating system and programming tools aka VS2010. Anyway the drive failed and Windows went kaput, however I am able to recover certain folders including all those related to VS2010.

My question is where will the old macros be stored and how if possible do I copy them to my new VS2010 install on my new O/S ? I don't want to have to re-program all my macros again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Visual Studio 2010 stores user recorded macros in "%userprofile%\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\VSMacros80", you can just copy that folder to the new drive to get them on the new install (you may have to load them manually).